# how to run custom function on an open tab within Chrome Extension using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that should manipulate the content of the currently open page (tab).

To take user input I use popup.html with a few input fields.
Input from this fields is transmitted to the page (content script) which executes the desired transformation.

The problem is that I cannot run a function which I define in a content script. 
I tried to define function in a content_script.js itself and tried to insert it into the page via

```
var new_script2 = document.createElement('script');
code = "function definition goes here";
new_script2.text = code;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(new_script2);
```

nothing works. Plus I also cannot see the jQuery objects in a content_script.js even if I insert them in a manifest as suggested [here](http://blog.michael-forster.de/2009/08/using-jquery-to-build-google-chrome.html)

Any ideas how to run custom function on an open tab within Chrome Extension after the event was generated in a popup???

[UPDATE]

Below is what I have now and I solved my problem, the key is to be careful with message passing and functions initialization.

My manifest looks as follows

```
{
  "background_page": "background.html",
  "name": "some",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "some",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "some",
    "popup": "popup.html"
  },
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "js": [ "javascripts/jquery-1.5.min.js", "javascripts/jquerylatest.js", "javascripts/content_script.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "file://*/*" ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
   } ],
   "permissions": [ "tabs", "http://*/", "https://*/" ]
}
```

In popup.html I create a button and assign an event handler that sends messages to the backgroundpage.html

```
    $( "#create-user" )
        .button()
        .click(function() {
            //~ alert(allFields.val());
            //~ var annot = [attrValue, attrType];
            chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {               
            chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {"attrValue" : attrValue.val(), "attrType" : attrType.val()}, 
            function readResponse() { console.log("got response in popup");} );
            window.close();
            });
        });
```

In backgroundpage I listen to messages send by a popup

```
var tab_id = -1;

chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        tab_id = tab.id;
    });

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender) {
    console.log("in bg.js addlistener method " + request);
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab_id, {file:"javascripts/content_script.js"});
    });
```

and redirects them further to the content script to use for page modification.
content_script listens as follows:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
//do your manipulation here
});
```

Finally, don't forget to include jquery libraries into the javascripts/ subfolder of your extension.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, injected Javascript functions don't get saved, unless they're attached to an event (like a `keypress` or an `onclick`). (someone please correct me if I'm wrong!)

Instead, I'd suggest using [`chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, details)`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) and writing out the code within the `details.code`, or having the code be in another content script .js file via `details.file` that you could inject.

But again, injected functions will be removed once the script is finished.
So put your function and other code in a content script, inject it, and your content script can use its function(s) until the script finishes.

Comment: Chris thanks for your comments, I have posted the sketch of my solution below. Thanks to the [article](http://www.mihswat.com/2011/03/02/writing-a-simple-google-chrome-extension/)

Comment: Cool. I think I also found today that `window.foo = function(...){...};` lets you call `window.foo()` from executed scripts, even after the execution has finished, or during the execution, without needing to define it again.